# Postgre: 2 different query but same result

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-views

I have problem with my queries in postgre sql.
First Query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, service_name, max(usluga)
FROM ( SELECT first_name, last_name, service_name, 
              count(scheduler_scheduleevents.id) as usluga
       FROM workers_workers
       LEFT JOIN scheduler_scheduleevents
         ON scheduler_scheduleevents.worker_id = workers_workers.id
        AND is_start_time = True
        AND is_active = False
        AND ( scheduler_scheduleevents.date < %s 
              or ( scheduler_scheduleevents.date = %s and time < %s ) )
       LEFT JOIN user_settings_userservices
         ON user_settings_userservices.id =scheduler_scheduleevents.service_type_id
       WHERE workers_workers.salonid_id= %s
         AND scheduler_scheduleevents.worker_id = %s
       GROUP BY workers_workers.id, service_name
     ) as x
GROUP BY x.first_name, x.last_name, x.service_name
```

And Second:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, service_name, min(usluga)
FROM ( SELECT first_name, last_name, service_name, 
              count(scheduler_scheduleevents.id) as usluga
       FROM workers_workers
       LEFT JOIN scheduler_scheduleevents
         ON scheduler_scheduleevents.worker_id = workers_workers.id
        AND is_start_time = True
        AND is_active = False
        AND ( scheduler_scheduleevents.date < %s 
             or ( scheduler_scheduleevents.date = %s and time < %s ) )
       LEFT JOIN user_settings_userservices
         ON user_settings_userservices.id =scheduler_scheduleevents.service_type_id
       WHERE workers_workers.salonid_id= %s
         and scheduler_scheduleevents.worker_id = %s
       GROUP BY workers_workers.id, service_name
    ) as x
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, service_name
```

First query should give me only 1 service which was made most time and second query should give me too only 1 service which was made least times.
Problem is both queries give me same results: list of all services and how many times each was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `distinct on`, I think.  The first query would be written as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (first_name, last_name) x.*
FROM (SELECT first_name, last_name, service_name, count(se.id) as usluga
      FROM workers_workers w JOIN
           scheduler_scheduleevents se
            ON se.worker_id = w.id AND is_start_time = True AND
               is_active = False AND
               (se.date < %s or
                se.date = %s and time < %s
               ) LEFT JOIN
           user_settings_userservices uss
           ON uss.id = se.service_type_id
      WHERE w.salonid_id= %s AND se.worker_id = %s
      GROUP BY w.id, service_name
     ) x
ORDER BY first_name, last_name, usluga DESC;
```

Your query fails because you are a including `service_name` in the aggregation keys in the outer query.  This is the same aggregation as the inner query, so it doesn't do anything.  You may *wish* that the `MAX()` function returns the row with the maximum value, but that is not what `MAX()` does

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The condition on `se.worker_id` turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, so there is no reason to use `LEFT JOIN` for that table.
- You might actually want the `LEFT JOIN`, if so, the condition should be on `w.id` instead.

Comment: It works big thanks. I must learn how distinct function works :P

Answer (score 1):

Use cte to make it more readable, then use `ROW_NUMBER()` to see whois the least and the mostly.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT first_name, last_name, service_name, 
           count(scheduler_scheduleevents.id) as usluga,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(scheduler_scheduleevents.id asc) ) as min_usluga,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(scheduler_scheduleevents.id desc) ) as max_usluga,
           FROM workers_workers
           LEFT JOIN scheduler_scheduleevents
             ON scheduler_scheduleevents.worker_id = workers_workers.id
            AND is_start_time = True
            AND is_active = False
            AND ( scheduler_scheduleevents.date < %s 
                 or ( scheduler_scheduleevents.date = %s and time < %s ) )
           LEFT JOIN user_settings_userservices
             ON user_settings_userservices.id =scheduler_scheduleevents.service_type_id
           WHERE workers_workers.salonid_id= %s
             and scheduler_scheduleevents.worker_id = %s
           GROUP BY workers_workers.id, service_name
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE min_usluga = 1
--WHERE max_usluga = 1
```